# How to transpose a table keeping their columns headers?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
+----+----+----+----+
| December|  January| 
+----+----+----+----+
     1         1
     2         2
     .         .
    31        31
```

You can build it with this code:

```
numbers = []
for i in range(1, 32):
    numbers.append(i)


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'December': numbers,
    'January': numbers})
```

Size: (31,2)

I want to plot a table like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+
| December     |  January     |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 1  2  3.. 31 | 1  2  3.. 31 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

The picture is only a example with 5 days values.
[image]

I tried this code:

[How to change a Pandas DataFrame into a column Multi-Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69250999/how-to-change-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-column-multi-index)

But with no results

I would appreciate any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), then convert [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html)

```
out = df.unstack().to_frame().T
```

*NB. if you don't want a MultiIndex: `out = df.unstack().droplevel(1).to_frame().T`.*

Alternatively:

```
out = df.reset_index().set_axis([0]*len(df)).pivot(columns='index')
```

Output:

```
  December           January          
         0  1  2   3       0  1  2   3
0        1  2  .  31       1  2  .  31
```

##### as a list

If you want to compact the data in a list, use the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0: df.to_dict('list')}, orient='index')
```

Output:

```
        December        January
0  [1, 2, ., 31]  [1, 2, ., 31]
```

Comment: Your code works fine to transpose but i want only 2 columns for the 31 days of every month. Thanks @mozway

Comment: @Javier your input/output are ambiguous, please provide them as DataFrame constructor. So you want a list in each cell?

Comment: I want to plot a image table like the picture i recently added @mozway

Comment: @Javier a picture is not reproducible, please provide code like: `df = pd.DataFrame({'December': [1,2,31], 'January': [1,2,31]})` and make sure this gives you the expected DataFrame!

Comment: Also, in your picture you don't have 2 columns, but 10. Pandas doesn't do merged cells, so either you want my option 1 or 2, anything else is not pandas.

Comment: I want the output part 1 of your code but with your code i got December and January header for every value. @mozway

Comment: This is the way it is with pandas, if you use jupyter the **display** will look merged